# Two MySQL query results are different, but shouldn't be

Tags: mysql

To the best of my knowledge, these results (especially the data in the 'destination' field) should be the same, but I can't find out why they're different:

```
mysql> select * from cc_did_destination where id_cc_did=1988\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            id: 2256
   destination: SIP/t564/12505551234
      priority: 1
    id_cc_card: 2157
     id_cc_did: 1988
  creationdate: 2012-01-31 07:59:01
     activated: 1
secondusedreal: 0
     voip_call: 1
     validated: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT cc_did.did, cc_did.id, cc_did_destination.destination     FROM cc_did, cc_did_destination  WHERE cc_did.iduser='2157' AND cc_did_destination.id_cc_card=cc_did.id\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        did: 7805551234
         id: 1988
destination: SIP/someuser
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        did: 6045551234
         id: 1997
destination: SIP/macaddress-1
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In fact, the data for the 'destination' field is correct in the first select statement. The data in the second query is old and should have been replaced with the data we see in the first query.

As per Rachel below, what I'm trying to do is this; Join this table:

```
mysql> SELECT destination, id_cc_card, id_cc_did FROM cc_did_destination where id_cc_card=2157;
+----------------------+------------+-----------+
| destination          | id_cc_card | id_cc_did |
+----------------------+------------+-----------+
| SIP/t564/12505551234 |       2157 |      1988 |
| SIP/testuser         |       2157 |      1997 |
+----------------------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To this table:

```
mysql> select did from cc_did where id=1988;
+------------+
| did        |
+------------+
| 7805553315 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Except when I try to do that with a JOIN statement, I get this instead:

```
mysql> SELECT destination, id_cc_card, did FROM cc_did_destination as A join cc_did on A.id_cc_card=cc_did.iduser WHERE A.id_cc_card=2157;
+----------------------+------------+------------+
| destination          | id_cc_card | did        |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
| SIP/t564/12505551234 |       2157 | 6045553939 |
| SIP/testuser         |       2157 | 6045553939 |
| SIP/t564/12505551234 |       2157 | 7805553315 |
| SIP/testuser         |       2157 | 7805553315 |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Which makes even *less* sense!

UPDATE: 
I found the problem, and it's all about matching the wrong fields. It should be:

```
WHERE cc_did.id=cc_did_destination.id_cc_did;
```

instead of:

```
WHERE cc_did.id=cc_did_destination.id_cc_card;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you're asking. You say "The data in the second query is old and should have been replaced with the data we see in the first query". So if the second query is old, and should be replaced...why does it matter that they're currently different?

Comment: The second *query* isn't old, the second query returns *old data* that no longer exists in the database. It's been replaced with the data that comes back when I do the first query.

Comment: A query cannot return data that don't exist in the database. The data is there. Data is not replaced or deleted by magic. We can't know what procedures, triggers you have and why you do not expect some rows not to be in your tables.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree. Which is why I'm baffled that my query is returning data that, well, isn't there.

Comment: You do not put both conditions in the `JOIN`. What happens if you change your last query to : `WHERE A.id_cc_card=2157 AND cc_did.id=1988` ?

Comment: I would fully expect that would only return one result. I want all the data for all the results of where id_cc_card = userid. id_cc_card is where one particular user's data exists, and I'm trying to find all the phone numbers (DIDs) that are bound to that customer.

Comment: Of the two tables I'm trying to join here, cc_did_destination has the most information and it's the most important. I'm just trying to complete the set by showing where id_cc_did associates in the cc_did database. I shouldn't need to generate a new query for each entry, which is computationally expensive in PHP.

Comment: Ugh. Found it. more like changing the query to `WHERE A.id_cc_card=2157 AND A.id_cc_did=cc_did.id`

Comment: I would like to thank ypercube and coffee and a good night's sleep for providing the answer to my question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way of looking at your queries

```
select * 
from A
where A.did = 1988

-- returns record where card = 2157
```

and

```
select * 
from B join A on A.card = B.id
where B.userid = 2157
```

Since you want the record where `a.card = 2157` and `a.card = b.id` then either

- Change your `where` statement so it is looking for `b.id = 2157` or `a.card = 2157`
- Or change your join so you're joining `a.card = b.userid`